# Bitmovin iOS PreprocessHttpRequestDelegate not called

Tags: ios, swift, xcode12, bitmovin-player

I set a simple player with Bitmovin player iOS like this:

```
func bind(videoPlayer: BitmovinPlayer.Player, url: URL) {
    // Update variables
    self.videoPlayer = videoPlayer
    self.videoPlayer?.add(listener: self)
    self.videoPlayer?.config.networkConfiguration.preprocessHttpRequestDelegate = self
    self.url = url

    let analyticsConfig = BitmovinAnalyticsConfig(key: Constant.BitmovinAnalytics.LICENSE_KEY)
    analyticsConfig.isLive = episode?.liveValue ?? false
    analyticsCollector = BitmovinPlayerCollector(config: analyticsConfig)
    analyticsCollector.attachPlayer(player: videoPlayer)
}
```

This method builds the player, but when I run a video the following method does not trigger the delegate:

```
func preprocessHttpRequest(_ type: String, httpRequest: HttpRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (HttpRequest) -> Void)
```

Other listeners work as expected.

Somebody had the same issue? I follow all the runcode looking for duplicate delegates but I just set the player once. No documentation or examples found for this feature.

Answer (score 0):

On iOS, the `preprocessHttpRequest` is only supported for DRM requests (like DRM license acquisition) as per the Bitmovin Player iOS API documentation [https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/api-reference/ios/ios-sdk-api-reference-v3#/player/ios/3/docs/Protocols/PreprocessHttpRequestDelegate.html](https://bitmovin.com/docs/player/api-reference/ios/ios-sdk-api-reference-v3#/player/ios/3/docs/Protocols/PreprocessHttpRequestDelegate.html#/c:@M@BitmovinPlayer@objc(pl)BMPPreprocessHttpRequestDelegate(im)preprocessHttpRequest:httpRequest:completionHandler:):

> Only changing DRM requests is currently supported.